# Using Puppet to manage shell commands

Tags: linux, ubuntu, deployment, puppet, vagrant

For example lets attempt to let Puppet [install the opengeo-suite](http://suite.opengeo.org/opengeo-docs/installation/linux/ubuntu/suite.html).

To do something like

```
wget -qO- http://apt.opengeo.org/gpg.key | apt-key add -
echo "deb http://apt.opengeo.org/suite/v3/ubuntu lucid main" >> /etc/apt/sources.list
```

we can use

```
exec {'getKey':
    command => "wget -qO- http://apt.opengeo.org/gpg.key | apt-key add -",
}

exec {'addRepo':
    command => "echo "deb http://apt.opengeo.org/suite/v3/ubuntu lucid main" >> /etc/apt/sources.list",
}
```

**Question #1:** If we run the puppet script again, won't the wget and echo be run twice? We will end up with  duplicate repo in `/etc/apt/sources.d`. Running `package { "opengeo-suite": }` twice doesn't attempt to install the package twice, it simply ensures that its installed.

**Question #2:** Doing `apt-get install opengeo-suite` there are several promopts for user input. When using `Package{"opengeo-suite":}` will Puppet somehow know the default input to use, or will it crash?

Comment: Please do not crosspost. http://serverfault.com/questions/501252/using-puppet-to-manage-shell-commands

Answer (score 1):

First, there are puppet-specific ways of doing this already:

https://serverfault.com/questions/111766/adding-a-yum-repo-to-puppet-before-doing-anything-else

Q1: Yes, everything will be run again and again. Usually you have to guard your exec to say "only if this file doesn't exist", or "check the website and update if different" or "force the file to have these contents".

Also, instead of appending to /etc/apt/sources.list, usually you can create /etc/apt/sources.list.d/myrepo.conf.

Q2: Puppet will probably hang. You could use "apt-get install -y package". But it's better to install the package using the Puppet resource designed for installing packages.

Comment: Sorry for question #2, I meant to ask whether `Package{"opengeo-suite":}` will fill in the default prompts for things like passwords. Updated question

Comment: for specific apt command, reuse this module :  https://forge.puppetlabs.com/puppetlabs/apt